# Can't to deploy angular app to azure web service. Don't have a permission

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a repository with my angular app. It works fine local.
I created pipline with yaml file in azure devops.

```html
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- masters

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm outdated
    npm run build:ssr --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'    

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'dist'
```

I have a release with this pipeline to my web app server in azure. This server with windows OS. I didn't have a problem with it when my yaml file was with `vmImage: ubuntu-latest`.

Pipeline builds good and deploy to app server was going good too.
No I have a problem with this in my browser when I try to open my app.

[image]

I heard that I need to change path mappings in configuration.

I tried a lot of many cases. `site\wwwroot`, `site\wwwroot\myappname`, `site\wwwroot\myappname\dist`.

And instead `You do not have permission to view this directory or page`
I have now this
[image]
My Angular app was created with default command `ng new test` and have all configs.
I really don't know what to do.

Comment: I would check the structure of the deployment. Check where it is actually deployed (under www, or where inside the App service directory)

Comment: @GeralexGR Sorry, I didn't understand. Where I need to check it? If I not mistaken default path is site\wwwroot

Answer (score 0):

- I have deployed an [Angular app](https://henriquesd.medium.com/deploying-an-angular-application-with-azure-pipelines-7c820116085f), initially I got the below error

[image]

- In Azure Portal => Configuration => Application Settings added `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` with value `true`

[image]

- And in `Path Mappings`, check whether Virtual Path is added or not.
  [image]
- Navigate to KUDU Console from portal
  ***Azure Portal*** => Your ***Web App*** => ***Advanced Settings*** => ***Go*** => ***Debug Console***, check whether the files and folder structures are correct and are under `wwwroot` directory
  [image]
- Now Iam able to access my Web App without any issues.
  ***Output :***

[image]
[image]

Comment: without any results :(

Comment: Add custom errors tag with mode=off in web.config file to check the detailed error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my folder assets. I use server render and I need to set folder path such way `site\wwwroot\app-name-from-package.json\browser`

and add `web.config` to `src` and set him in `angular.json` in assets

`"assets": ["src/web.config"]`